# kafkaTemplate.send(message) is trying to connect infinite times on "Authentication Failure"

Tags: java, authentication, apache-kafka

How to avoid this infinite loop. How to add error Handling in this case. If any credential mismatch, it should try 3 times and should stop reconnecting

```
2022-10-19 16:03:32.410  INFO [,,,] 828 --- [ad | producer-2] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Failed authentication with (Authentication failed: Invalid username or password)
2022-10-19 16:03:32.412 ERROR [,,,] 828 --- [ad | producer-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Connection to node -2 () failed authentication due to: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password
2022-10-19 16:03:34.417  INFO [,,,] 828 --- [ad | producer-2] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Failed authentication with  (Authentication failed: Invalid username or password)
2022-10-19 16:03:34.419 ERROR [,,,] 828 --- [ad | producer-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Connection to node -2 () failed authentication due to: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password
2022-10-19 16:03:36.338  INFO [,,,] 828 --- [ad | producer-2] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Failed authentication with (Authentication failed: Invalid username or password)
2022-10-19 16:03:36.340 ERROR [,,,] 828 --- [ad | producer-2] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-2] Connection to node -1 () failed authentication due to: Authentication failed: Invalid username or password
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer due to my low reputation but I want to enrich the problem. I also faced this problem with kafka client v. 2.8.2 and have an infinite logging of such pair of lines. In JVM there are >1000 threads named "kafka-producer-network-thread" and I think it all started from this error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.SystemTime.waitObject(SystemTime.java:55) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerMetadata.awaitUpdate(ProducerMetadata.java:119) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.waitOnMetadata(KafkaProducer.java:1047) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:906) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:885) ~[kafka-clients-2.8.2.jar:?]
```